# Neutrinos travel faster than the speed of light

Tags: escape-velocity

If neutrinos travel faster than the speed of light does the calculation for the speed of light become obsolete. IE is there now a new formula for calculating speed/velocity through space/vacuum.

Comment: Neutrinos don't travel faster than light. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light_neutrino_anomaly

Comment: If neutrinos *did* travel faster than light, the formula for speed (distance divided by time) would be unchanged. It's just most of the rest of physics that would have had to be redefined.

Comment: Ok understand not a space exploration question. please close question

Answer (score 3):

The neutrino speeds were found to not be faster than light after all.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faster-than-light_neutrino_anomaly#End_results)